# $20$ people sit at a round table, how many ways can we choose $3$ with no $2$ being neighbors?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

My thought process to this problem was as follows:
$1st$ move you have $20$ choices, when you pick you eliminate $3$ people, the first person and their two neighbors. The $2nd$ move you have $20-3$ people to choose from so $17$. And so on.

Does: $20 \cdot 17 \cdot 14$ make sense as an answer?

Comment: No, because they might _share_ neighbours, which means you haven't counted all the possibilities.

Comment: Yes good point, naive of me to think so quickly thanks..gotta re-think this through

Comment: Also note that the way you counted them, you are essentially saying that picking persons number $1,5,9$ is different from picking persons $9,1,5$ is different from $1,9,5$, is different from... You get the idea. You need to divide by six somewhere at the end.

Comment: So the highest number of possibilities may be `(20*17*15)/(3!)` because we at best, can eliminate only two instead of three people when picking the second person. Plus divide by 6 to account for order not mattering?

Comment: I think, instead of thinking about excluding neighbours, the easiest solution is to use the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: true blue anil's answer is much better than mine, being generalized to $\frac{n}{n-k}\times{n-k\choose k}$ for counting the number of ways we can choose $k$ of $n$ persons sitting around a table such that no $2$ are neighbors.

Comment: @Logophobic: Thank you for your gracious comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Another way:**

Looking clockwise, attach a "general" person to each of $3$ "special" persons $\fbox{SG}$

There are now $3$ boxes + $14$ individuals $= 17$ entities

Place the boxes in $\binom{17}{3}$ ways,
but since you are allowing each entity only $17$ starting points instead of $20$,
multiply by $\frac{20}{17}$ to get ans $= \frac{20}{17}\times\binom{17}{3} = 800$

Answer (score 4):

There are $20$ ways to choose $3$ people sitting in three consecutive seats. There are $20\cdot16$ ways to choose $3$ people where $2$ are sitting together with the third sitting apart from them. Thus we have $17\cdot20=340$ choices that do not qualify. Excluding these from the total, the number of ways to choose $3$ with no $2$ being neighbors is:
$${20\choose3} - 340 = 800$$

Comment: I'm glad my plow-ahead, brute-force answer agrees with your elegant one.

Comment: @John Actually, I believe your solution is better. It looks like it could be generalized. See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1630839/ways-to-create-a-quadrilateral-by-joining-vertices-of-regular-polygon-with-no-co) that I answered earlier today. It asks for groups of $4$ with no neighbors.

Answer (score 3):

Call the oldest person at the table $1$, the person to his left $2$, and so forth until you get around to $1$'s immediate right, which is $20$.  Now order each qualifying triple $A,B,C$ such that $1 \leq A < B < C \leq 20$ to count each one exactly once.

Starting with $A=1$, we can have $(1,3,5), (1,3,6), ..., (1,3,19), (1,4,6), ..., (1, 17, 19),$ which by my counting gives $T_{15} = 120$ ($T_n$ is the triangular number).

The case $A=2$ is the same because we can now go up to $20$.

The case $A=3$ gives $T_{14} = 105$ choices.  The case $A=4$ gives $T_{13} = 91$ choices.  Continuing the pattern to the end, $A=16$ gives $T_1 = 1$ choice.

Adding all of these up we find the answer is

$$S = T_{15} + \sum_{n=1}^{15} T_n = 800.$$